# YAML + Ruby usage

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, yaml

I'm trying to make testcase using Selenium WebDriver and Ruby. I started learning Ruby a few times ago.
I created the testcase:

```
    require "test/unit"
    require "selenium-webdriver"
    require "yaml"

    thing = YAML.load_file('config.yaml')
    puts thing.inspect

    class Test < Test::Unit::TestCase

      def setup
        browser = thing('browser')
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for browser
        @driver.get 'http://google.com'
        @driver.manage.delete_all_cookies
      end

      def teardown
        @driver.close
      end

      def test_page_search
      end

    end
```

I decided to use YAML for config file where I will can change  and  for WebDriver.

config.yaml:

```
    # Set browser (firefox, ie, chrome, opera)
    browser: ":firefox"

    # Search query
    search_query: "ios testing"
```

But when I'm running the testcase I'm getting the error:
"test_yaml.rb:11:in `setup'"

Comment: Can you please show more lines of the error message?  We see here only the line number, not the actual error.

Comment: user3431099 - When I set up an environment just like you have built the error I get is "NameError: undefined local variable or method `thing' for..." and from what I can tell it doesn't think your variable 'thing' has been initialized yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
browser = thing('browser')
```

Did you mean:

```
browser = thing['browser']
```

If you're trying to access the browser key, that should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

I resolved the issue:

```
require "test/unit"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "yaml"

class Test < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    thing = YAML.load_file('config.yaml')
    puts thing.inspect

    browser = thing['browser'].to_sym
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for browser
    @driver.get 'http://google.com'
    @driver.manage.delete_all_cookies
  end

  def teardown
#    @driver.close
  end

  def test_page_search
  end

end
```